# AngularJS - ngModel inside ngRepeat doesn't change the scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a survey app. A user can select questions of the type "text", "paragraph", "checkbox", and then type their question. If this is a checkbox, then they get to add as many options as they want.

The code below is incomplete and only shows the case for "checkbox". It's the directive's link function:

```
scope.questions = [];
scope.addQuestion = function(type)
{
    var question = {
        type : type,
        question : ''
    };
    if (type == 'checkbox') {
        question.options = [];
    }
    scope.questions.push(question);
}

scope.addOption = function($questionIndex)
{
    var question = scope.questions[$questionIndex],
        option   = 'Option ' + (question.options.length+1);

    question.options.push(option);
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions" class="questions">
    <!-- The Question -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- This is where the question field goes -->
    </div>

    <!-- The Answer -->
    <div class="row">

        <!-- Checkbox answer -->
        <div class="columns large-2" ng-if="question.type == 'checkbox'">Options</div>
        <div class="large-8 columns" ng-if="question.type == 'checkbox'">
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="option in question.options">
                <div class="large-offset-1 large-9 columns">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="option" />
                </div>
                <div class="large-1 columns end" ng-click="removeOption($parent.$index, $index)">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Button for adding more options MARKUP -->
            <div ng-click="addOption($parent.$index)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Add a new Question MARKUP -->
<!-- This calls addQuestion(type) with type being 'text', 'paragraph', 'checkbox', etc -->
```

The problem is: when I add more options, and modify the value, and then add to add another option, the values reset to the default.

Right now, the `ng-model` inside the `input` is the variable `option` that comes from the `ng-repeat="option in question.options track by $index"`. IF I change this `ng-model` to `ng-model="question.options[$index]"` THEN everything works just fine. Why is it that `option` of `ng-repeat` is not passed by reference? Is this because `option` here is a just a text variable? If so how can I solve this?

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VVbTigJdi5m3vonky2O4?) for this

Comment: Please try and clean up that code showing us only the relevant parts.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv, I removed all the other codes. The only problem is inside the `ng-repeat` on `options`. I think the problem is that the variable `option` is just a text, and JavaScript by default doesn't pass text as a reference? Because If I use `ng-model="question.options[$index]"` everything works fine

Comment: Yup. Reference issue.

Comment: But why? That's kind of odd that Angular doesn't pass it by reference for `ng-repeat`